# How do I stop anyone from adding a column to few tables in Postgres 9.6?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers

I want to prevent people from adding/dropping a column to 3-4 tables. They should contact my team before adding/dropping a column. I know for this purpose, I need to use event_trigger. When I created event_trigger it is blocking from adding column to any table, I know there is something wrong with the logic, but can't seem to figure it out. In short, 'Alter Table Add/Drop Column' is what I want to prevent.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.abort_adding_column()
RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$

DECLARE
obj record;

BEGIN
For obj IN SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables AND table_schema IN ('schema1') AND table_catalog = 'database1';
LOOP
RAISE EXCEPTION 'command % is not allowed on %s, see blah blah for more details.', tg_tag;
END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

Only a superuser and the table owner can run `ALTER TABLE`.

Since your users are not allowed to login as superuser (right?), all you need to do is change the ownership of the tables to a different user. Then give the users all permissions on the tables that they need to have.

Using a trigger is not a good solution, because the table owner can just drop the trigger.

Comment: We use flyway for any db changes, so technically anyone can modify the table since flyway is the superuser. We don't have any individuals as super users except DBAs. Hence going to this route. 

The reason we want to prevent is we have a view sitting on these tables and we should modify view when column is added/dropped. View is simple select *, but when we add/drop a column, view is not automatically updated.

Comment: Flyway should *not* run as superuser. Superusers are only required for administrative tasks. So the solution can still work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution though, I am using ddl_command_end instead of ddl_command_start.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.abort_adding_column()
RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
obj record;
BEGIN
FOR obj IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()
LOOP
IF  obj.object_identity in ('schema1.table1', 'schema2.table2') AND obj.schema_name in ('schema1', 'schema2')
THEN
RAISE EXCEPTION 'command % is not allowed on % in % schema in the blah blah ', tg_tag, obj.object_identity, obj.schema_name;
END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
$$;


CREATE EVENT TRIGGER abort_ddl ON ddl_command_end
EXECUTE PROCEDURE schema.abort_adding_column();
```